# jQuery animation slow and choppy

Tags: jquery, css, animation

My jQuery animation is running really slow and choppy. I feel like I have tried everything to speed it up, like stopping existing animations before starting new ones, only perform animations if required and using jquery.gsap.js. I have also tried using css animation but cant seem to get the smoothness required. Does anybody have any ideas how I can speed it up.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mux61p5s/3/) link

```
<section id="vertical-strips">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image:url(im1.jpg)">t1</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(im2.jpg)">t2</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(im3.jpg)">t3</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(im4.jpg)">t4</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(im5.jpg)">t5</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(im6.jpg)">t6</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(im7.jpg)">t7</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

```css
#vertical-strips {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#vertical-strips ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#vertical-strips ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 2vw;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```js
items = $("#vertical-strips ul li");
items.each(function(i) {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        size = $(window).width()/items.length; 
        items.each(function(j) {
            if (j != i) {
                if ($(this).width() > size - (40.0/items.length) + 5) {
                    $(this).stop();
                    $(this).animate({width:size - (40.0 / items.length)},  "fast");
                }
            }
        }); 
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).animate({width:size + 40},  "fast");    
    },
    function() {}
);
});
```

Comment: They're smooth for me. This might be an issue with your system's horsepower more than anything else.

Comment: Smooth for me as well. I've found that when using jquery animations, if I have the dev tools panel of my browser open, things tend to run much more choppy. Maybe part of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"linear"` to `easings` property ; could also adjust `$.fx.interval` - before animation begins

```
$.fx.interval = 100;

items = $("#vertical-strips ul li");
     items.each(function(i){
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                size = $(window).width()/items.length; 
                items.each(function(j){
                    if(j != i ){
                        if($(this).width() > size - (40.0/items.length) + 5 ){
                            $(this).stop();
                            $(this).animate({width:size - (40.0/items.length)},  "fast", "linear");
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).animate({width:size + 40},  "fast", "linear");  
            },
            function(){
            }
        );
    });
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mux61p5s/9/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, take a look at your animate() function:

```
$(this).animate({width:size + 40},  "fast");
```

Your "fast" option can be changed to any value really. You could set your animation timing to be faster. Simply replace your "fast" value with "5" for example.

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mux61p5s/8/).

Take a look at animate's properties doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties).

Answer (score 0):

What i did here is instead mentioning slow,fast,... I **just gave it 10 seconds**.

> Note:If you want still more speed decrease it by giving value smaller
>   then 10

It might help you

[WORKING:DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mux61p5s/7/)

**JS**

```
  items = $("#vertical-strips ul li");
         items.each(function(i){
            $(this).hover(
                function(){
                    size = $(window).width()/items.length; 
                    items.each(function(j){
                        if(j != i ){
                            if($(this).width() > size - (40.0/items.length) + 5 ){
                                $(this).stop();
                                $(this).animate({width:size - (40.0/items.length)}, 10);
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                    $(this).stop();
                    $(this).animate({width:size + 40}, 10); 
                },
                function(){
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: in js 1000 is one second -- 10000 is 10 seconds -- 10 is a tenth of a second